Genesis Chapters 10 and 11 split seems to be in wrong location?
Regarding the Tower of Babel narrative...
I have posted elsewhere about the timeline problem of Babel happening only ~100 years after the flood. Population, technology, etc. issues are all raised with such a short time frame. That question was closed as I had too many questions at once.
I have found an alternate theory that I'd like to get feedback on.
What if...Chapter 10 should end AFTER the Babel account, with Chapter 11 beginning before Shem's genealogy? This would place Babel after the language dispersion of the families, so 'whole earth' would be using the other definition more like whole area or country - this is not an uncommon interpretation from my understanding.
Babel would be the end of the section that contains Nimrod (Ham's descendant), who may be the start of the clan that built Babel (Babel is mentioned with him). I have seen him mentioned as the one who built the tower. That then places Peleg (Shem's descendant) in a different section - and his name 'Division' could refer to something else. It usually means something 'cut into parts' more than 'scatter' from what I've seen, so that would also fit better. It is Peleg's birth time that causes the short time issue.
I realize this is not the traditional understanding. However, it would clear up issues on the timeline. It could also place Babel at a time closer to archeological findings of when this type of brick was used.
The only other seemingly viable option is that this is an illustration/parable/polemic that was inserted here and not a literal event - at least not in this time frame. I'm tagging this as contradiction because the timeline seems to contradict...well...math, history, and population growth.
Please let me know your thoughts on this.
Editing to add what the main question is. It seems the traditional understanding is that Babel happened when Peleg was born ~100 years after the flood, tying Babel to the genealogy following it. My question is if it is actually tied to the genealogy before it (containing Nimrod, founder of Babel). Or possibly something that happened later and is non-chronological. It makes more sense to me if it's tied to the genealogy before it, if it is connected at all. But the 'chapter' breaks I see in English language Torah has the break before the Babel story rather than after.
A comment says that there is an open section surrounding the Babel story in the Torah before Chapters were put in, which would line up with what I'm thinking.

Note the commonly printed chapter breaks are of non Jewish origin and regularly don't match the expected content.

There is an "open" section break before chapter 11, but also after 11:9.

@shmosel So you are saying there is a break before and after the Babel story? Could it have been 'inserted' here as an aside, perhaps not even chronological? I guess I'm wondering if it's possible that Babel happened even with Nimrod's descendants and not him. And then, not at all connected to Peleg in Shem's genealogy.

Could you please [edit] to make it very clear what  particular question this post is driving at?
